# Using 2 XSLT substring function in template

Tags: xslt, substring

Why cant I use this XSLT string function in a template?

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text,'2') and substring($text,1,(string-length($text)-1))" />
```

Here is the template:

```
<!-- Template to remove double quotes if available in first and last position of any field -->
  <xsl:template name="remove-quotes">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
   <xsl:param name="quot" select="'&quot;'"/>
   <xsl:param name="trim1" select="substring($text,'2')"/>
   <xsl:param name="trim2" select="substring($text,1,(string-length($text)-1))"/>
  <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="starts-with($text,$quot) and ends-with($text,$quot)">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-quotes">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$trim1 and $trim2"/> 
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

Invoked by:

```
<xsl:call-template name="remove-quotes">
 <xsl:with-param name="text" select="XXXXX"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us reproduce the problem - and explain what exactly the problem here is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your template is trying to do, but certainly this part makes no sense:

```
<xsl:call-template name="remove-quotes">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$trim1 and $trim2"/> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

`and` is Boolean operator. An expression that contains `and` returns a result of either `true()` or `false()`.

Same thing with:

```
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text,'2') and substring($text,1,(string-length($text)-1))" />
```

---

### Added:

To remove either a leading or a trailing quote or both, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:variable name="lead" select="number(starts-with($text, '&quot;'))" />
<xsl:variable name="trail" select="number(ends-with($text, '&quot;'))" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1 + $lead, string-length($text) - $lead - $trail)" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the parameter "text"  I am trying to trim the first and last character. How do I use both the substring() functions in a single call?  

I tested my template. It allows me to use either **"substring($text,'2')"** or **"substring($text,1,(string-length($text)-1))"** 

I get either this output : **This is a sample text"**  or this one: **This is a sample text"** 

Say for examle: 

text = **"This is a sample text"**  

My desired output should be : **This is a sample text**

Comment: @Shankar **1.** Please add this information to your question. -- **2.** See the added part of my answer.

Comment: Awesome Mike. It trimmed the lead and trailing double quotes for me. Thanks a lot. I appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 0):

XSLT Template:

```
    <!-- Template to remove trailing and leading double quotes from the fields -->
     <xsl:template name="remove-quotes">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="quot" select="'&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="lead" select="number(starts-with($text, '&quot;'))"/>
    <xsl:param name="trail" select="number(ends-with($text, '&quot;'))"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with($text,$quot) and ends-with($text,$quot)">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-quotes">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 1 + $lead, string-length($text) - $lead - $trail)"/> 
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Invoke like this:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="remove-quotes">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="SampleText"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
```